# Does MongoDB produce a single file like sqlite does for an individual database? Can it?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.2

Does MongoDB store it's data like SQLite does at all?  A single file.  From what I could see it is using "wiredTiger," but I can't find a specific file for my database I created.

Comment: This isn't a current option (as at MongoDB 3.4), but what is your goal as far as having a single file? Are you aiming to backup a single database?

Comment: I really just wanted to know how it worked.  I thought I was missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As at MongoDB 3.4, all of the standard storage engines (WiredTiger, MMAPv1, ..) create multiple files in the [`dbPath`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.dbPath). For example, in WiredTiger there are a number of metadata files, journal files, and a file per collection and per index (see: [Why is an empty MongoDB database so big?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37758988/1388319)). Multiple files generally allow more granular concurrency and storage management; single-file databases are more common for [embedded use cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database).

The file and directory layout is dependent on the storage engine and server configuration options, so it is conceivable that someone could develop a new MongoDB storage engine which has a more concise file layout (but I'm not aware of anyone having done so).

Irrespective of the layout on disk, you could use the standard `mongodump` utility to create a single [compressed & archived backup](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/archiving-and-compression-in-mongodb-tools) of a database to copy and restore on another system using `mongorestore`. The archive feature is available in MongoDB 3.2 or newer. For more information, see [Archiving and Compression in MongoDB Tools](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/archiving-and-compression-in-mongodb-tools).